# Orfeo mshift segmentation asks for condition

Tags: parameters, orfeo-toolbox, qgis-3, image-segmentation

I'm trying to run a segmentation using the mean shift. I leave all the parameters as default, but when I run it, it says "Wrong or missing parameter value: Condition".
Condition is not a parameter for the meanshift, but for the cc algorithm.

When running meanshift as batch processing, you can see that a parameter called "Condition" is requested.
The image is a small Landsat composite.

[image]

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.4.4 btw

Comment: have you tested other OTB tools (e.g. BandMath) to see if OTB is correctly linked. There is no "condition" parameter in the Meanshift algorithm as far as I know, so this could be an issue with the installation. The OTB plugin with QGIS 3 has been rewritten, therefore there could be some small bugs. As a workaround, I suggest you to use the OTB tools from Monteverdi.

Comment: I have the same issue right now... :) :(

Comment: I never managed to solve it. I resorted to eCognition.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in QGIS 3.6 and QGIS 3.8

Note: For using QGIS3.8+, please uninstall otb plugin because provider is now integrated into processing core.